# How does heroku store its authentication on its command-line app?

Tags: ruby, security, authentication, command-line, design-patterns

I assume that when you first install the heroku gem and you're prompted to put in your username/password, it sends that username/password to its server to validate.

How then does heroku (or any other command-line apps for that matter) store that validated token on the file system securely and then transmit it together when it runs other commands like 'heroku create' for validation?

I'm using heroku as an example here because it is the only one that I could think of which does what I'd like to do at the moment.

Comment: Looking at auth.rb(fixlr's suggestion below), I realize heroku is not only sending your public ash key but also storing an API Token. Why do they have two separate forms of authentication. Wouldnt one be suffice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Heroku now spells out how they store their auth token for the Heroku CLI in pretty good detail here: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/authentication

Relevant excerpts:

> API token storage
>
> The Heroku command-line tool stores API tokens in the standard Unix
>   file ~/.netrc. The netrc format is well-established and well-supported
>   by various network tools on unix. With Heroku credentials stored in
>   this file, other tools such as curl can access the Heroku API with
>   little or no extra work.

```
cd ~
ls .netrc
ls: .netrc: No such file or directory
$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: me@example.com
Password:
$ cat .netrc
machine api.heroku.com
  login me@example.com
  password c4cd94da15ea0544802c2cfd5ec4ead324327430
machine code.heroku.com
  login me@example.com
  password c4cd94da15ea0544802c2cfd5ec4ead324327430
```

Comment: Heroku has also published a rubygem for handling `.netrc` files: https://github.com/heroku/netrc

Answer (score 3):

Heroku uses your login once to figure out who you are, then sends your public ssh key to their server so when you push to their git repo they know who you are([docs](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart#step_3_login)).

Other apps handle things differently. Some create a `.<something>` file in your home directory that contains an API token.

Answer (score 2):

The heroku gem stores your credentials in **~/.heroku/credentials** and the related code is in [lib/heroku/auth.rb](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/lib/heroku/auth.rb).

Comment: this is no longer correct, Taytay has the correct answer below

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the implementation.

A common way of doing something like this is storing an auto-generated key-pair in a temporary file. The public key is passed to the server, and the private key is encrypted with a symmetric session key (that expires after a short duration, or upon logout).

The permissions field of this file is set to r-------- (read only by user.)

/tmp is generally used because many operating systems clean it up periodically. (Some even use an in-memory device.)

Implementations may differ, e.g., SSH keys are usually generated just once, not encrypted with a session key (but may expire), and are stored in ~/.ssh.